# What are UI primitives

Tags: web

What are UI primitives?

> if you find
>   yourself wishing that you had a different set of UI primitives to work
>   with, you just invent new ones.
>   [https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/props.html]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The building blocks of your UI. Lets take html as an example: div, span, form etc are UI primitives, a div containing a span and a form is not a primitive. But, if you often need the structure "div containing span and form" you can use react to turn it into a primitive and just use it

Comment: Thank you, this clarified a lot for me

Answer (score 0):

Some kind of UI entity that can be used to build more sophisticated UI constructs.

For example a hypertext link can be thought of as a UI primitive, as can some type of 'out of the box' border for a UI element that is provided by some kind of UI framework.